# Excluding the pattern for vim syntax highlighting

Tags: regex, vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am trying to adjust the reStructured text syntax highlighting in vim. I have tried several vim regexes to get highlight working for below two examples, but I am unable to. If I use search/highlight function all below regexes do the job, but for highlighter (syn match) it is not working. Maybe I need to change syn match to something else?

This is the text example I am looking at in rst file:

```
.. item:: This is the title I want to highlight

    there is some text here which I do not care

.. item-matrix:: This is the title I want to highlight
    :source: XX
    :target: YY
```

Regexes that match the text:

```
[.+].*[:+] \zs.*
\(.. .*:: \)\zs.*
```

When putting that to syn match it does not work (.vim):

```
syn match rstHeading /[.+].*[:+] \zs.*/
```

I know I am close because above example matches for

```
..:: This is highlighted as rstHeading
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When integrating with an existing syntax script (here: `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/rst.vim`), you need to consider the existing syntax groups. `:syn list` shows all active groups, but it's easier when you install the [SyntaxAttr.vim - Show syntax highlighting attributes of character under cursor](https://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=383) plugin. (I maintain an [extended fork](https://github.com/inkarkat/SyntaxAttr.vim).)

On your example headings, I see that the `.. item::` part is matched by `rstExplicitMarkup`, and the remainder (what you want to highlight) by `rstExDirective`.

Assuming that you want to integrate with (and not completely override) these, you need your syntax group to be *contained* inside the latter. This can be done via `containedin=rstExDirective`.

Another pitfall is that `\zs` limits the highlighting, but internally still matches the whole text. In combination with syntax highlighting, this means that the existing `rstExplicitMarkup` prevents a match of your pattern. If you use a *positive lookbehind* ([`:help /\@<=`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/pattern.txt.html#%2F%5C%40%3C%3D)) instead, it'll work:

```
syn match rstHeading /\%([.+].*[:+] \)\@<=.*/ containedin=rstExDirective
```

Of course, to actually see any highlighting, you also need to define or link a *highlight group* to your new syntax group:

```
hi link rstHeading Title
```

Comment: This indeed was combination that solves the problem. Thanks for the plugin for syntax highlighting. I was using the simple thingy from official help which does not enable this tracking.