# Render space if it have multi space in Vim

Tags: vim, vim-plugin

I used:

```
set listchars=tab:→\ ,trail:·,precedes:←,extends:→,nbsp:·,space:·
```

to render space and tab character.

But I want to show only >=2 space, I don't want to display if It has one space between other characters.

(It is the same of `"editor.renderWhitespace": "boundary"` in vscode)
[image]

Can I do it in Vim? (`config` or `plugin`)

Thank you.

**Edit:** I use:

```
if exists('space_match')
  call matchdelete(space_match)
endif
let space_match = matchadd('Conceal', '\v( @<= )|(  @=)', -1, -1, {'conceal': '·'})
```

- I use priority `-1` to compatible with `indentLine`
- `( @<= )` to match a space after another space
- `(  @=)` to match a space before another space

and remove space in `listchars`:

```
set listchars=tab:→\ ,trail:·,precedes:←,extends:→,nbsp:·
```

Thank Ben Knoble so much to help me find that!!!

Comment: @D.BenKnoble, looks like you're right.

Comment: Welp, crud. I may have misunderstood the question. You don't want to hide the extra spaces. You want to show them as `.`. Is that right?

Comment: I want display 2 whitespace is `··` 3 whitespace is `···`, but one whitespace is normal space

Comment: @Hongarc got it: i think i can do that with conceal. Ill play around and edit my answer below

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using conceal, there are a couple of ways this can go, depending on what you want to achieve. Since we are using conceal, you'll want to remove `space` from `'listchars'`.

> I'll be using `matchadd()` below, but you can theoretically do something similar with `syn-conceal`. The difference is that a match is local to a window. Syntax is available where defined—you could use any filetype or other mechanism to set this via syntax.
>
> I assume that the regex `\s` (match whitespace) matches what you need. If you need only spaces, change `\s` to  (a single space character) in the regexp.
>
> I assume you can read vim regexp. The help pages are extensive, but do note below that I use `\v` to explicitly set the magic type (`matchadd` is sensitive to regex-influencing options like `'magic'`) and I use `\zs` where appropriate to start the match.
>
> I'll be using the test text below.

#### Test file

```
word word  word   word
word word  word   word
```

### `set conceallevel=1`

At level 1, we're allowed to use replacement characters in our matches.

So, we could replace all the extra spaces with, e.g., a `.` to make them standout:

```
let space_match = matchadd('Conceal', '\s\@<=\s+', 10, -1, {'conceal': '.'})
```

(10 is the default priority, and -1 requests a new ID for the match.)

### Cleaning up

To get rid of the match/conceal, you can simply

```
call matchdelete(space_match)
```

---

The OP has stated that the following worked best for the question:

```
let space_match = matchadd('Conceal', '\v( @<= )|(  @=)', -1, -1, {'conceal': '·'})
```

- priority `-1` to compatible with `indentLine`
- `( @<= )` to match a space after another space
- `(  @=)` to match a space before another space

Comment: Unfortunately, testing out `let space_match = matchadd('Conceal', '\v\s\zs\s', 10, -1, {'conceal': '.'})` reveals that matches don't "overlap" well...

Comment: Try to use `\@<=` instead of `\zs`: `let m = matchadd("Conceal", ' \@<= ', 10, -1, {'conceal': '.'})`

Comment: @user938271 I'm so glad that worked—can you explain why? Is it because `' \@<= '` doesn't actually consume the first space, where with `\zs` it does?

Comment: Yes, that's pretty much it. `\zs` limits the highlighting, but internally, the whole text is still matched (including what precedes `\zs`). This is also explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53730038/9780968