# Vim regex to split string but keep the separators

Tags: regex, vim

To my current understanding, the pattern below should work (expected `['bar', 'FOO', 'bar']`), but only the first alternative is found (zero-width matches after FOO, but not before).

```vim
echo split('barFOObar', '\v(FOO\zs|\zeFOO)')  " --> ['barFOO', 'bar']
```

Netiher could I solve it with lookahead/lookbehind.

```vim
echo split('barFOObar', '\v((FOO)\@<=|(FOO)\@=)')  " --> ['bar', 'bar']
```

Compare this with e.g. Python:

```vim
echo py3eval("re.split('(?=FOO)|(?<=FOO)', 'barFOObar')") " --> ['bar', 'FOO', 'bar']
```

(Note: in Python, a paren-enclosed `'(FOO)'` would also work for this.)

Why don't the above examples in Vim's regex work the way I thought they should? (And also, is there a more or less straightforward way to do this in pure Vimscript then?)

Comment: After split, can you join with a string like `*FOO*` and then split again on `*`.  Not efficient, but maybe that doesn't matter.

Comment: `Netiher could I solve it with lookahead/lookbehind.`: there is a mistake in your regex, you should not escape the lookarounds if you use `\v`. Try this: `echo split('barFOObar', '\v((FOO)@<=|(FOO)@=)')`.

Comment: @user938271 Wow, thanks very much :) The problem is essentially solved, but I'm still wondering about the behavior of the first version with `\zs` & `\ze`.

Comment: `but I'm still wondering about the behavior of the first version with \zs & \ze` `\zs` and `\ze` limit the text matched by the regex, but internally the whole text is still matched, which makes a difference when the regex has overlapping matches (once `\zs` and `\ze` are removed).  The same pitfall applies to syntax rules; see https://stackoverflow.com/a/53730038/9780968.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to accomplish that direct result using a single `split()`. In fact, the docs for `split()` mention this particular situation of preserving the delimiter, with:

> If you want to keep the separator you can also use `\zs` at the end of the pattern:
>
> ```
> :echo split('abc:def:ghi', ':\zs')
> ['abc:', 'def:', 'ghi']
> ```

Having said that, using both a lookahead and a lookbehind *does* actually work. In your example, you have a syntax error. Since you're using verymagic mode, you shouldn't escape `@`, since it's already special. (Thanks [@user938271](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9780968/user938271) for pointing that out!)

This works:

```
:echo split('barFOObar', '\v((FOO)@<=|(FOO)@=)')
" --> ['bar', 'FOO', 'bar']
```

---

Regarding using the markers for `\zs` and `\ze`:

```
:echo split('barFOObar', '\v(FOO\zs|\zeFOO)')
" --> ['barFOO', 'bar']
```

So the first trouble you have here is that both expressions on each side of the `|` are matching the same text "FOO", so since they're identical, the first wins and you get it on the left side.

Change order and you get it on the right side:

```
:echo split('barFOObar', '\v(\zeFOO|FOO\zs)')
" --> ['bar', 'FOObar']
```

Now the question is why the second token "FOObar" isn't being split since it's matching again (the lookbehind case splits this one, right?)

Well, the answer is that it's actually being split again, but it matches on the first case of `\zeFOO` one more time and produces a split with the empty string. You can see that by passing a keepempty argument:

```
:echo split('barFOObar', '\v(\zeFOO|FOO\zs)', 1)
" --> ['bar', '', 'FOObar']
```

---

One question still unanswered here is why the lookahead/lookbehind *does* work, while the `\zs` and `\ze` doesn't. I think I addressed that somehow in [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/22431/18609) to regex usage in syntax groups.

This won't work because Vim won't scan the same text twice trying to match a different regex.

Even though the `\zs` makes the resulting match only include `bar`, Vim needs to consume `FOO` to be able to match that regex and it won't do so if it already matched it with the other half of the pattern.

A lookbehind with `\@<=` is different. The reason it works is that Vim will first search for `bar` (or whatever text it's considering) and then look behind to see if `FOO` also matches. So the pattern gets anchored on `bar` rather than `FOO` and doesn't suffer from the issue of trying to start a match on a region that already matched another expression.

You can easily visualize that difference by performing a search with Vim. Try this one:

```
/\v(\zeFOO|FOO\zs)
```

And compare it with this one:

```
/\v((FOO)@<=|(FOO)@=)
```

You'll notice the latter one will match both before *and* after FOO, while the former won't.

---

> Compare this with e.g. Python [`re.split`] ...
>   in Python, a paren-enclosed `'(FOO)'` would also work for this.

Vim's and Python's regex engines are different beasts...

Many of the limitations in Vim's engine come from its ancestry from vi. One particular limitation is capture groups, where you're limited to 9 of them and there's no way around that.

Given that limitation, you'll find that capture groups are typically used less often (and, when used, they're less powerful) than in Python.

One option to consider is to use Python in Vim instead of Vimscript. Although typically that impacts portability, so personally I wouldn't switch for this feature alone.

---

> is there a more or less straightforward way to do this in pure Vimscript then?

One option is to reimplement a version of `split()` that preserves delimiters, using `matchstrpos()`. For example:

```
function! SplitDelim(expr, pat)
    let result = []
    let expr = a:expr
    while 1
        let [w, s, e] = matchstrpos(expr, a:pat)
        if s == -1
            break
        endif
        call add(result, s ? expr[:s-1] : '')
        call add(result, w)
        let expr = expr[e:]
    endwhile
    call add(result, expr)
    return result
endfunction
```

Answer (score 1):

You could first replace `FOO` with `-FOO-`, then split the string. For example:

```
:echo split(substitute('barFOObarFOObaz', 'FOO','-&-','g'),'-')
['bar', 'FOO', 'bar', 'FOO', 'baz']
```

Comment: I'm aware of this trick, but it cannot be guaranteed that those wrapping characters won't appear in the original segments, so while this workaround might work most of the time, it is not a satisfying solution in my case. Moreover, I'd also like to understand the gotchas of Vim's regex engine, as I clarified the question.